# Create document using Mongoose.js with Projection and Unique validation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there any way to have the same options as `findOneAndUpdate()` when creating a document. I realize I can set `upsert: true` but I am looking to throw an error if the document already exist.

So say I have Courses in a database and when to insert a new one. If I use `.create()` I get no ability to project, or use lean. :dis 
If I use `findOneAndUpdate` then it does not throw an Error for a document with a duplicate field as it is updating as existing document which I do not want to do.

Basically I would like the abilities that come with .findOneAndUpdate() but I want it to throw an error if it finds a document, since I am searching for it based off the field which I wish to be unique

Comment: This _might_ also help some: `const _doc = doc.toObject(); delete _doc.prop1;`. (Using `delete` directly won't work on Mongoose document objects because they're configured to be non-editable. `toObject()` turns them into plain objects first. Then `delete` will work.)

Answer (score 0):

By looking to your problem , you can try the following approach

```
function updateUser(user,cb){
    UserModel.find({name : user.name}, function (err, docs) {
        if (docs.length){
            cb('Name exists already',null);
        }else{
             user.save(function (err, returned) {
             var leanObject = returned.toObject();
             assert.equal(leanObject.schema, null);
             });

        }
    });
}
```

So , in the above code , you find for the document and and if we get the result non-empty , we can consider it as an error otherwise we can save that document as new entry .

Comment: Thanks for the response. However `.save()` has the same problem as `.create()` which does not allow me to specify a projection, or lean, or any other options lol.

Basically I would like the abilities that come with `.findOneAndUpdate()` but I want it to throw an error if it finds a document, since I am searching for it based off the field which I wish to be unique.

Comment: Save, Update, Create, and Remove are not "queries", so they don't take the .lean() directive as is.
You could use the .toObject() method on the returned object to get it without the schema . you can see my updated code

Comment: So for now I am just using a query condition that I know will fail to find. That way I force the upsert and get all the benefits! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

So to accomplish the desired goals I have done the below. Where I use a query condition that I **know** will fail. That way I am forcing the upsert and get the benefits of the options.

```
  async addCourse(input, projection = {}) {
    const { name } = input;

    const conditions = { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId() };
    const newCourse = await this.model.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, input, {
      upsert: true,
      new: true,
      lean: true,
      projection,
      runValidators: true,
      context: 'query',
      setDefaultsOnInsert: true,
    });

    return newCourse;
  }
```